# Spotify installation issue on Xcode 10

Tags: ios, swift, spotify, xcode10

Trying to install Spotify pods and the following error persists:

> Error installing Spotify-iOS-SDK [!] /usr/bin/curl -f -L -o
>   /var/folders/px/qxl7j4592255xcgm71h6dtj40000gn/T/d20181003-3772-zoxnr8/file.zip
>   https://github.com/spotify/ios-sdk/archive/beta-25.zip --create-dirs
>   --netrc-optional --retry 2

Can anyone please suggest?

Comment: Show the Podfile

Comment: # Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
 platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'SpotifyDemo' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!
 pod 'Spotify-iOS-SDK'

end